# Angular ng-options: compare by id

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can I set the ng-model for a select to the key of an object?
In the example below 'item1' should be selected by default.
(I don't want to compare objects by reference)

```
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <select 
        ng-model='selectedId'
        ng-options='value for (key, value) in items'>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.selectedid = 1;

    $scope.items = {
        1: 'item1',
        2: 'item2'
    }   

});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h7yb4bys/

Comment: I don't understand why so many people on SO try to use objects like they are arrays. Why can't you just declare items as an array?

Comment: Because I often have to search the value for a certain id. items[2] is a lot easier (and faster?) then a for loop.

Comment: See Aditya's response below. You can still use an array and use the id to lookup the item based on index.

Comment: Bad example. The id is random. {9: 'some item', 11: 'other item'}. This means if I want the item with id 11 I can just use items[11]

Comment: If you really want you can just use `var array = [];` array[9] = 'some item', array[11] = 'other item'; I doubt you will be looking up items by id very often anyway. Unless you have huge arrays you won't notice the difference in performance. Using an object for a list of items just makes your code ugly

Comment: I do lookups by id very often and I find the code much easier/shorter then using arrays. I think it just depends what kind of data you have and app you are making. But I agree that often an array is better. Just not always :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout http://jsfiddle.net/oj884ofm/

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.selectedId = '1';

    $scope.items = {
        1: 'item1',
        2: 'item2'
    }   

});
```

Comment: Ah, I can't use integers. It needs to be a string. Thanks!

Comment: And your variable name selectedId was not proper. In view you were using selectedId and in controller you were using selectedid.

Answer (score 0):

You should try '`key as value for (key, value) in items`':

```
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
    <select 
        ng-init="selectedId='1'"
        ng-model='selectedId'
        ng-options='key as value for (key, value) in items'>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely consider using arrays instead of objects. You can still say 'items[2]' with an array. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wpk69xq9/) is the fiddle and the code.

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2'];
   $scope.selectedId = $scope.items[0];
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
 <select ng-model='selectedId' ng-options='item for item in items'></select>
</div>
```